# linux bash error: -bash: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash

After I login to Linux every time, it shows :
    -bash: /usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/xx/bin: No such file or directory

I notice that there is  a '=' in it,  but I don't know why.
My .bash_profile:

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

$PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_73
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
```

I want to set the JAVA environment , and it works ,but after I edit profile,it shows the bash error.
How could I fix it?

Comment: `PATH=whatever`, not `$PATH=foobar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin` does not do what you want. After substituting the values for variables (`PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` and `HOME=/home/xx`) it executes a command:

```
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/xx/bin
```

which explains the error.
To do a variable assignment, remove `$` from variable name on the left side of the assignment:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```